# Wine 1.5.5-SAI doesnt work PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux, 19.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.04 on my siblings computer. Paint Tool SAI is their main art program, and I've managed to get it to run successfully with the latest wine version provided with PlayOnLinux. However, I cannot get pen pressure to work. I've read that the only way to get pen pressure to work is to use the wine version that PlayOnLinux provides "1.5.5-SAI", but this crashes every time I attempt run it, whereas other later Wine versions I have tried do work. Is there some kind of workaround to get pen pressure to work on the later wine versions, or a way to fix the older wine version so that it runs?